# How to use foreign keys in django?

Tags: python, django, view, foreign-keys

I can't seem to be able to use foreign key in django. I have a rental spaces network website that offers books. I've created a "Rental" model and a "Book" model and I've created a foreignkey for book model to be attached to a rental space. In admin panel everything works as it should, but I can't get it to show on website. I want to have several books in rental space 1 and none in rental space 2. I don't know how to manage it in views.py

my models :

```
class Rental (models.Model):
    rental_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rental_number=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    rental_adress=models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.id, self.rental_name)

class Book(models.Model):
    # autor, tytul gatunek, isbn, id w wypozyczalni
    book_author=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book_isbn= models.CharField(max_length=17, unique=True)
    BOOK_GENRE= (
        ('SF', "Sci-Fi"),
        ("ROM", "Romance"),
        ("HIS", "Historical"),
        ("HOR", "Horror"),
        ("THR", "Thriller"),
        ("BIO", "Biography"),
        ("KID", "For kids"),
        ("FAN", "Fantasy"),
    )
    book_genre=models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=BOOK_GENRE)
    book_rental=models.ForeignKey(Rental, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1, related_name="display")

    class Meta:
        constraints =[
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['book_author','book_title'], name='unique_book'),
        ]
```

my views:

```
 class BookListView(ListView):
    model = Book
    template_name='book.html'

class BookDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name='book_detail.html'

class RentalListView(ListView):
    model = Rental
    template_name='rental_list.html'

class RentalDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Rental
    template_name='rental_detail.html
```

and my htmls look like this:

```
<h1 style="font-size:11px; text-align:right;"><a href="{%url 'home' %}">Powrót do strony głównej</a></h1>
{% block content %}
    
    {%for book in object_list%}
        <div class="book-entry">
            <h2><a href="{% url 'book_detail' book.pk %}">{{book.book_title}} {{book.book_genre}}</a></h2>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

By doing it this way it shows books in both rental spaces, instead of just one, the one that has books in it. I have no idea how to do it any other way, I've been working with django for just a couple of days, and I don't understand everything yet. It's clear that that html just prints every book there is but how to make it print only those belonging to rental space 1?
I followed a guidebook but it led me only to this point.

Comment: you are iterating over an `object_list`. how do define it? maybe you can do some filtering there?

Comment: What about overwriting the ```get()``` Method of your View?

Comment: Do not put answers in question posts. Post an answer post. After minimum wait time you can accept it to show it was the (best) answer. Click on 'edited' to see the raw text to cut & paste your raw answer text. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time.  [ask] [answer] [Help] PS [mre]